# Handling ServletExceptions that occur

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am building a simple web application. In my *doPost()* method, when I forward to a JSP, if a ServletException occurs, I throw a *ServletException*. In my web.xml file I have declared an error page to catch a 500 error. The application works fine on my GlassFish server, but when I deploy to a Tomcat server, I am being directed to my problem.jsp page. How can I get some details on the cause of the error?

Here is how my error page configured in *web.xml*:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/problem.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem.jsp can access this request attribute to give you a feed about the nature of the exception :

- ***javax.servlet.error.exception***

You can use these as follows :

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
     {      
         Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
     }
```

You can afterwards spy on the type of the exception by doing :

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("Exception Type : " +  throwable.getClass( ).getName( ));
```

---

**Resources**

You can learn more on this [web page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm). You'll find some other attributes you'll be wanting to check for extensive details about your error.

Comment: Do I have to set the throwable in the request? Like request.setAttribute("throwable" throwable);

Comment: In your doPost method for example. You can just start smoothly by trying things out, for that use a simple `System.out.println(throwable.getClass().getName());` in your doPost method, you'll notice the console showing an info message that indicates the type of the exception.

Comment: Thats the thing, the server is not on my machine, so I dont have access to the console. Is there a way I can pass the throwable to the jsp as an attribute right before I throw the ServletException?

Comment: Found the error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: The way you're configuring your web.xml will let you get any exception (server distant doesn't matter) giving it results from an error-code 500. Your problem.jsp can then access that request attribute and create a throwable object upon it. You should include all the exception handling in this problem.jsp.

Comment: It is the throwable object in itself. Have you read the article ? I think you still didn't understand the principl here..